# How to perform collaborative filtering in R

Tags: r, data-mining, collaborative-filtering

I'm have matrix data containing some null values. To fill the null values, I'd like to perform collaborative filtering. As I am studying for R, rather I'd like to use R.

So, Does anyone know how to perform collaborative filtering in R?

Comment: I would start by looking at the `recommenderlab` package, which I found via `library("sos"); findFn("{collaborative filtering}")`

Comment: Any particular variant or just user based will do?

Comment: **[What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)**

Answer (score 3):

Like Ben Bolker said, recommenderlab is the package in R that you can use. A detailed document for the same is available at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/vignettes/recommenderlab.pdf